# Type Error when using DDT for Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python, data-driven

I am learning Selenium with python, so please excuse my amateur questions, I am trying to run a simple Data driven test where selenium will enter a few different names on the Name field.

The Page code is as below:

```
class AddClients(BasePage): 
    log = cl.customLogger(logging.DEBUG) 
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        self.driver = driver

    def appy(self,name):                     
        self.clickAddBtn()
        self.enterEmpname(name)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.clickCancel()
```

I am running the tests on a different script

```
from pages.clients.addclient_page import AddClients
from utilities.teststatus import TestStatus
import unittest
import pytest
from ddt import ddt,data, unpack


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("oneTimeSetUp","setUp")
@ddt
class AddClientTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def classSetup(self,oneTimeSetUp):
        self.ac = AddClients(self.driver)
        self.ts = TestStatus(self.driver)


    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    @data(("employeronefffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"),("tester"))
    @unpack
    def test_adding_client(self,naming):
        self.ac.appy(naming)
        time.sleep(3)
```

But when I try to run the script it throws the error below:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.0.2, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1 -- c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\python.exe
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: C:\Users\Fake\PycharmProjects\Kode, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors 

============================== ERRORS ===============================
____________ ERROR collecting tests/clients/addclient_test2.py ____________
c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py:209: in fget
    return self._obj
E   AttributeError: 'Module' object has no attribute '_obj'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
tests\clients\addclient_test2.py:11: in <module>
    class AddClientTesttwo(unittest.TestCase):
c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\ddt.py:258: in ddt
    add_test(cls, test_name, func, **v)
E   TypeError: add_test() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.32 seconds ===========================
```

I am running all the test on py.test. Note: the browser doesn't even launch.

```
@data(('emploer',''), ('tester',''))
```

When I add a null value to data, the browser launches and does the sign in process but then fails with:

```
    self = <tests.clients.addclient_test2.AddClientTesttwo testMethod=test_adding_client_1___emploer____tester__>

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self):
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
E       TypeError: test_adding_client() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\ddt.py:139: TypeError
```

Comment: It's pretty complicated code. What are your Python and Selenium skills: Are you expert python coder? Do you have some simpler example where browser does launch? Can you distill some smaller example which still fails?

Comment: It looks like you gave the code for addclient_test.py, not addclient_test2.py, which is where the error is coming from . . . .

Comment: Actually that wasn't the issue I pasted the wrong error message from addclient_test here.
I figured out  the issue was I was using the "unpack" decorator, even though just one argument was required "naming" "unpack" decorator should only be used when you have more than one argument.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the @Unpack decorator on

```
@data(("employeeeee"),("testeeer"))
def test_adding_client(self,naming):
```

Looks like the unpack decorator should be used when there are more than one arguments

```
@data(("employeeeee","CEO"),("testeeer","CFO"))
@unpack
def test_adding_client(self,naming,position1):
```